# Generalizing iteraton method in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose I have some custom collection of `Foo`s:

```
struct Bar {}
struct Foo {
    bar: Bar
}
struct SubList {
    contents: Vec<Foo>,
}
```

and suppose I also have a `SuperList` which is a custom collection of `SubList`s:

```
struct SuperList {
    contents: Vec<SubList>,
}
```

`SubList` and `SuperList` each provide a method `bars`:

```
impl SubList {
    fn bars(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Bar> + '_ {
        self.contents.iter().map(|x| &x.bar)
    }
}
impl SuperList {
    fn bars(&self) ->  impl Iterator<Item = &Bar> + '_ {
        self.contents.iter().flat_map(|x| x.items())
    }
}
```

I want to define a trait that provides a method `items`, and implement that trait on `SubList` and `SuperList` so that `SubList::items` is equivalent to `SubList::bars` and `SuperList::items` is equivalent to `SuperList::bars`, so that I can do this:

```
fn do_it<T: Buz<Bar>>(buz: &T) {
    for item in buz.items() {
        println!("yay!")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foos = vec![Foo{ bar: Bar{} }];
    let sublist = SubList{ contents: foos };
    do_it(&sublist);
    let superlist = SuperList{ contents: vec![sublist] };
    do_it(&superlist);
}
```

I can do what I want with dynamic dispatch:

```
trait Buz<T> {
    fn items(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &T> + '_>;
}
impl Buz<Bar> for SubList {
    fn items(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Bar> + '_> {
        SubList::bars(self)
    }
}
impl Buz<Bar> for SuperList {
    fn items(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Bar> + '_> {
        SuperList::bars(self)
    }
}
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
trait Baz<T> {
    fn items(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> + '_;
}
impl Baz<Bar> for SubList {
    fn items(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Bar> + '_ {
        SubList::bars(self)
    }
}
impl Baz<Bar> for SuperList {
    fn items(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Bar> + '_ {
        SuperList::bars(self)
    }
}
```

```
(error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types)
```

[Here's a playground link to what I've tried so far](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62782b9299c3c1276737908d9dfb29a9)

How can I define a trait `Baz` which provides an `items` method to abstract over the `bars` methods of `SubList` and `SuperList` without using dynamic dispatch?

Comment: In short: you cannot yet do that, at least not without crazy workarounds. This is blocked by generic associated types (GATs). If it weren't for the `+ '_`, it would be easily possible with an (non-generic) associated type. But by using the `self` lifetime, this gets tricky. Sorry for plugging my blog, but I extensively discussed this and explored workarounds [here](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2018/08/03/solving-the-generalized-streaming-iterator-problem-without-gats.html), if you're interested. But in short: no really good workaround exists IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I don't have a good enough understanding of the theory yet to know how to apply a lot of what you describe but it's gotten me started. I still am not understanding how generic associated types would allow  this to work - I'm trying to return two different types of iterators, `std::slice::Iter` and `std::iter::FlatMap`, and treat them as the same thing, and I don't see how GATs would get me there because the associated type in the impl for `SubList` would be different than the associated type for `SuperList`, and thus the traits would be different types, no?

Comment: Sorry, my comment should have been an answer. So now I wrote one! I hope the explains everything. And you are right, GATs are not the only blocker here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not really possible in Rust right now. Not by design, but simply because some relevant type level features are not implemented or stabilized yet.

Unless you have spare time, an interest in type level stuff and are willing to use nightly: **just use boxed iterators**. They are simple, they just work, and in most cases it will likely not even hurt performance in a meaningful way.

---

You're still reading? Ok let's talk about it.

As you intuitively tried, `impl Trait` in return type position would be the obvious solution here. But as you noticed, it doesn't work: `` error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types ``. Why is that? [RFC 1522](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md) says:

> **Initial limitations**:
>
> `impl Trait` may only be written within the return type of a freestanding or inherent-impl function, not in trait definitions [...] Eventually, we will want to allow the feature to be used within traits [...]

These initial limitations were put in place because the type level machinery to make this work was/is not in place yet:

> One important usecase of abstract return types is to use them in trait methods.
>
> However, there is an issue with this, namely that in combinations with generic trait methods, they are effectively equivalent to higher kinded types. Which is an issue because Rust's HKT story is not yet figured out, so any "accidental implementation" might cause unintended fallout.

[The following explanation in the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md#limitation-to-freeinherent-functions) is also worth reading.

That said, some uses of `impl Trait` in traits can be achieved already today: with associated types! Consider this:

```rust
trait Foo {
    type Bar: Clone;
    fn bar() -> Self::Bar;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Foo for A {
    type Bar = u32;
    fn bar() -> Self::Bar { 0 }
}

impl Foo for B {
    type Bar = String;
    fn bar() -> Self::Bar { "hello".into() }
}
```

This works and is "basically equivalent" to:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn bar() -> impl Clone;
}
```

Each `impl` block can choose a different return type as long as it implements a trait. So why then does `impl Trait` not simply desugar to an associated type? Well, let's try with your example:

```rust
trait Baz<T> {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = &Bar>;
    fn items(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}
```

We get a `missing lifetime specifier` error:

```
4 |     type Iter: Iterator<Item = &Bar>;
  |                                ^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

Trying to add a lifetime parameter... we notice that we can't do that. What we need is to use the lifetime of `&self` here. But we can't get it at that point (in the associated type definition). This limitation is very unfortunate and is encountered in many situations (search term "streaming iterator"). The solution here are GATs: generic associated types. They allow us to write this:

```rust
trait Baz<T> {
    //       vvvv  That's what GATs allow
    type Iter<'s>: Iterator<Item = &'s Bar>;
    fn items(&self) -> Self::Iter<'_>;
}
```

GATs are not fully implemented and certainly not stable yet. See [the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265).

But even with GATs, we cannot fully make your example work. That's because you use iterator types that are unnameable, due to using closures. So the `impl Baz for ...` blocks would not be able to provide the `type Iter<'s>` definition. Here we can use another feature that is not stable yet: `impl Trait` in type aliases!

```rust
impl Baz<Bar> for SubList {
    type Iter<'s> = impl Iterator<Item = &'s Bar>;
    fn items(&self) -> Self::Iter<'_> {
        SubList::bars(self)
    }
}
```

This actually works! (Again, on nightly, with these unstable features.) You can see your full, working example [in this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7840d9108ab498239f8d10582f36826d).

This type system work has been going on for a long time and it seems like it's slowly reaching a state of being usable. (Which I am very happy about ^_^). I expect that a few of the foundational features, or at least subsets of them, will be stabilized in the not-too-distant future. And once these are used in practice and we see how they work, more convenience features (like `impl Trait` in traits) will be reconsidered and stabilized. Or so I think.

Also worth noting that `async fn`s in traits are also blocked by this, since they basically desugar into a method returning `impl Future<Output = ...>`. And those are also a highly requested feature.

---

**In summary**: these limitations have been a pain point for quite some time and they resurface in different practical situations (async, streaming iterator, your example, ...). I'm not involved in compiler development or language team discussions, but I kept an eye on this topic for a long time and I *think* we are getting close to finally resolving a lot of these issues. Certainly not in the next releases, but I see a decent chance we get some of this in the next year or two.